# how to add extra product field in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a online electronic parts store build with Prestashop 1.6.

Now I want to add some extra fields for each product (for example: Part datasheet, footprint, 3D model and ...). These field may have different types (file, checkbox, text and etc).

can anybody help me to do this.

the final thing I want is something similar to **Newark Website**. I have highlighted the field in the below image.

I found this [tutorial](https://mypresta.eu/en/art/developer/new-field-product-backoffice.html), but the problem is he didn't say anything about adding this field to front-end and also nothing about field type.

[image: Screenshot of Newark Website]

Comment: did you search something on google ,, did you try the code? . Show the sample code.

Comment: @ArshSingh Yes, I found this link > https://mypresta.eu/en/art/developer/new-field-product-backoffice.html. but I can't define checkbox for file field.

Comment: Have you tried looking into product `attributes` ?